# SOAP call to WCF Web Service from Ruby on Rails App

Tags: c#, node.js, ruby, wcf, soap

I need to call an old 3rd-party WCF web service (*which I have no control over*) from my Ruby on Rails app. My biggest problem is that the request content-type has to be `application/soap+msbin1` (aka binary encoding, not text/utf8). I quickly found out that I couldn't use Postman/SoapUI/curl/etc for this reason, but I have been able to successfully call the service via test C#/.NET solution.

Here is the working code in .NET

```
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding("CustomBinding_IReceiveDataService");
EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("https://sample.com/ReceiveDataService.svc");

ReceiveDataServiceClient client = new ReceiveDataServiceClient(binding, ep);
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxx";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xxx";
ReceiveDataData rd = new ReceiveDataData();

rd.FileNumber = "TEST-123456";
rd.Field1 = "This is an example from .NET";
rd.Field2 = "This is another example.";

ReceiveDataResponse res = client.ReceiveData(rd);

return res.ToString();
```

Here is the `CustomBinding` as received by the WSDL from the WS:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBinding_IReceiveDataService">
        <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="SecureConversation"
            requireDerivedKeys="false" includeTimestamp="false" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
            canRenewSecurityContextToken="true">
            <secureConversationBootstrap defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default"
                authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" requireDerivedKeys="true"
                includeTimestamp="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
                <localClientSettings detectReplays="false" />
                <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" />
            </secureConversationBootstrap>
            <localClientSettings detectReplays="false" />
            <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" />
        </security>
        <binaryMessageEncoding />
        <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

So my question is: **What's the best way to call this service from my Ruby on Rails app?**

The options I have considered are:

1. Using the `Savon` gem (I'm not sure if this gem supports binary encoding, I can't find anything to say that it does or does not)
2. Write a small .NET DLL and call it from Ruby (This seems overly complicated as the only way I could find to achieve this would be to go `Ruby -> C++ -> .NET DLL`)
3. Write a .NET DLL and call it from NodeJs (I think this is going to be my easiest option but again I'm not sure.)

As stated, I believe my best bet will be option 3 but maybe I am over-complicating the binary encoding piece of it so any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I think there's a solution you can try: write a WCF service that calls the WCF service that transmits binary data, and then convert it to text/utf8 data. But there is a warning about **Managed Debugging Assistant**.